# .net standard how to kill all child process

Tags: c#, process, .net-standard-2.0

I using `Process.Kill()`. But this does not kill the child process， the child process is still there after my program finishes. I have to kill it manually.

for example, we use the `Process` call `cmd` to open `ping <ip> -t`. Then we kill the Process and observe that the ping has not been kill.

I found some answer like c#/WMI, but this can't be used on the .net standard.

Comment: Why not recursively iterate all child processes and kill them by yourself? (depth-first).

Comment: @Uwe Keim I used Process call cmd to open the specified program, cmd open program I can not get the process id

Comment: You can collect all active processes with the same path (full path to executable) and kill each process: `Process.GetProcessesByName(<exe_path>)`

Comment: @Stefan It is not safe to shut down by name because it is possible to run multiple instances at the same time

Comment: @MengHanYu Perhaps share some more info. For starters the code that you tested and also tell us on what condition you want to kill the process.

Comment: @Stefan I have added some examples that are easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe can copy the code here：

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Utilities/ProcessExtensions.cs#L14